# Is it safe to use this app and will it cause problems in 6.0?

Tags: security, phone-app, 6.0-marshmallow

[Classic Dialpad  for KitKat and Lollipop](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/apps-games/classic-dialpad-kitkat-lollipop-t2942320)

Just wanted to check if there's any reason not to use this, here's what the permissions looks like.

<sub>Click image to enlarge</sub>

[image: picture]

I'm assuming its just a shortcut to the dialer with the keypad active, but it doesn't hurt to check.

Answer (score 0):

According to the screenshot, the app is not requesting any special permissions.
If your phone is not rooted I'd say: Its safe.

Comment: Is there a way to know if its safe while rooted? I extracted the apk using apktool, but I'm not sure what does what.

EDIT: actually, I'd get a SU request if it tried to do anything wouldn't I

Comment: Yes. SuperSU should pop up with a su request.